# Manipulating elements in a Python List

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a strange requirement where I need to manipulate the contents of a list based on certain rules.

My list is as below:

```
lst = [
    '%s###timestamp', 
    "TRANSLATE(%s, ',', '')###sales", 
    "TRANSLATE(%s, ',', '')###units", 
    "TRANSLATE(%s, ',', '')###counting_units", 
    "TRANSLATE(%s, ',', '')###standard_units"]
```

As per the requirement, every '%s' has to be replaced by 'SPLIT(expld ' and the final result has to be like below:

```
res = [
    """SPLIT(expld, "###")[0] AS timestamp""", 
    """TRANSLATE(SPLIT(expld, "###")[1], ',', '') AS sales""", 
    """TRANSLATE(SPLIT(expld, "###")[2], ',', '') AS units""", 
    """TRANSLATE(SPLIT(expld, "###")[3], ',', '') AS counting_units""", 
    """TRANSLATE(SPLIT(expld, "###")[4], ',', '') AS standard_units"""]
```

where [0],[1],[2] and so on represents the index of the list.

Why I need to create the 'res' like this because I need this list later to construct a Hive Query.

In my attempt so far, I have just been able to replace '%s' value with 'SPLIT(expld ' which was straightforward.

```
splitExpr = [w.replace('%s', 'SPLIT(expld ') for w in lst]
```

I'm still trying to figure out how can I get the desired result in this case.

Comment: I don't understand what `TRANSLATE(SPLIT(expld, "###")[4], ',', '') AS standard_units` is? Is it a string?

Comment: If you have `‰s`, then you can use String formatting rather than replacing

Comment: @ThatBird yes, the elements of this list have string values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = [w.replace('###', ' AS ').replace('%s', 'SPLIT(expld, "###")[{}]'.format(i)) for i, w in enumerate(lst)]
```

Use the enumerate function to get the index and string simultaneously. I also replaced '###' with ' AS ' before the split you suggested.

List comprehensions like this one are concise but you might consider using a regular for loop for more readable code.

Comment: @bstrauch24 I came up with a similar answer (but will not bother to post it). However, the replaced text has the single quotes escaped - seemingly because of the double quotes. Do you get this behaviour, and do you understand why?

Comment: @KolaB try printing out each string in the list, and you'll see that the escapes are gone. In a list, each string has quotes around it which conflict with the quotes inside. It's just a presentation thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a `range` method -

```
[x[i].replace("TRANSLATE(%s, ',', '')###", "TRANSLATE(SPLIT(expld, \"###\"[{}],',', '') AS ".format(i)) if "TRANSLATE" in x[i] else x[i].replace("%s###","SPLIT(expld, \"###\")[{}] AS ".format(i)) for i in range(len(x))]
```